# "Kundalini" experiences during meditation

Tags: theravada, personal-practice, meditation-effects

Can anyone advise on experiences of "kundalini" (energy rushing up the spine and out the crown of the head) during meditation?  I have experienced this for years and am wondering if it has an understanding/meaning in the Theravada tradition.  The energy has a physical effect (jolting the body) and a mental one (like temporarily cleaning out the conscious mind).  Thank you greatly.

Comment: that sounds so awesome!!! I'm a beginner and the only thing I closely experience is when an idea suddenly rushes at me, i.e. a Eureka! moment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've experienced this myself on a number of occasions though I never heard it called kundalini. Sometimes the experience has been exactly as you describe it. Sometimes it's a tingling feeling all over the body. Sometimes it feels like electric jolts. Sometimes the jolts manifest in physical movement.

I was advised that this was probably a manifestation of piti (rapture). This would be in the context of the [rupa-jhana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dhy%C4%81na_in_Buddhism#Rupa_Jhana_related_factors) factors going from

- applied thought (vitakka)
- sustained thought (vicāra)
- joy/rapture/happiness (pīti)
- happiness/pleasure/bliss (sukha)
- equanimity (upekkhā)
- one-pointedness (ekaggatā)

So you could expect this to be proceeded by strengthening concentration and perhaps develop into a calmer more pleasurable state (sukka). [Here is a further breakdown of piti](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C4%ABti#Fivefold_classification) which again feels familiar to me. Yours might fit into the last two classification - exalting and fulfilling rapture.

From conversations I had with other people the exact manifestations of these very much depend on the type of person. I'm more the anxious, type A type of person so I feel a lot of energy. I often feel it trapped in me then it comes out in great surges. Other people never feel this.

I think the important thing with these kind of experiences is not to get attached to them and not to pursue them. They are as they are and they come and go. In the experience themselves there is no insight nor is there lasting benefit. Like everything these things are ultimately impermanent and unsatisfactory.

Comment: Crab Bucket, you have answered a question that I have carried around for a decade.  Can't thank you enough.  Your explanation and some further research I just did on Piti have brought it home.  Also, I totally agree that the experience is transient (not to be held on to).  It had become a distraction for me, not understanding it.  Now, I will receive it differently.  With Metta.

Answer (score 1):

I practice according to Theravada texts and my sister practices likewise but the kundalini path. We have been in training for 6-9 years and have a good relationship.

In my experience there is no way to bridge anything.

My sister talks about kundalini arising and chakras activating, i can narrow this to perception of a pleasant feeling, whether this is some sort of physical response to breathing exercises, a feeling born of pelvic exertion or a pleasant feeling born of seclusion. I as a Theravadin can't tell and furthermore i don't care much.

As a Theravadin when i hear about people's meditative attainments that commonly people would talk about as "deep meditation", "meditative trance", in the "mystical" or "transcendental" or "lifechanging" categories of description.

What i care about is were you are that time experiencing discursive thought, what was the perception, can the perception be described in terms bodily sensations, color or form. If this is the case then i maybe this is a form-jhana or maybe something like a high for physiological response.

If can not be described in terms of a bodily sensation such as a pleasant feeling in the head or the body, nor a feeling of air blowing, of the hardness of the limbs, warmth or coolness, nor floating or flowing, then i think maybe this person attained to formless perception.

Either way, i don't care about these attainments and am more interested in a person not being fixated in wrong views. I hold a person who has just faith if not understanding of the correctly exposed Dhamma to the point where he can discern what is rightly spoken as Dhamma, i hold him infinitely higher than a person who mastered all feeling & perception attainments.

Answer (score 0):

For years I have experienced the jolts of energy rushing up my spine and releasing through my skull, giving the sensation of hair being pulled upwards during anapana sati meditation from time to time and found that it was the result of a strong positive emotion in the field of meditation practice in general and the benefits of the practice in my life. Recently I experienced , after decades of meditation practice, with great intervals though, a sudden very tangible feeling of cold air blowing slightly into my face. At first I felt somewhat stunned and distracted by it and struggled not to look for explanations for it. I am not much of a reader about theoretical elucidation on meditation practice since it became clear to me that there are many different views and interpretations about the subject and that the only way to know is to experience. 
Personally I never heard from my former teacher about any relation between anapana sati and prana (chi). I see this experience now as just one of those things that happen during meditation practice. The most important lesson I derive from this experience is not to let it distract me during meditation practice and around it by wanting to rationalize it. It will pass eventually.
Be well.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had similar experience. I was 4 days into a 10 day silent meditation retreat doing 'vipassana' style meditation. So for 3 days was mostly silent, no phones, lotta nature, read a Raymond chandler book which was against rules but oh well, lotta meditating i guess it's pretty common style just focusing on your natural breathing sensations right at the nostrils.  Anyhow on day 4 we went from 'normal' meditation technique to focus out attention on small portions of our body starting at the base of the head and sort of moving our focus and attention around to different parts of the body, slowly and methodically. Basically if I could keep myself very still and breathe a bit heavier I could feel waves of intense electric feeling (sort of felt like dmt body high, no crazy psychedelic brain stuff tho) all over but wherever I had focused my attention too was more pronounced. Closest thing to what I'd call a religious type experience, and since I'm all sorts of atheist i figured must be a glitch in my brain (hallucination or psyched myself into it or whatever) or must just be how it works and therefore repeatable and explainable.  So I bailed on the monk training and totally plan to check it out further but had too much choring I'd left behind back home. Really cool experience, I hope I can repeat it but that's my tale. Cheers.