# Diagnose: Samatha practice led to an urge to contract PC muscle, and pleasant vibrations resulted

Tags: personal-practice, meditation-body

During the last part of a concentration exercise (focusing eyes on a point between eyebrows) I felt a need to contract my [Pubococcygeus muscle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pubococcygeus_muscle). During contraction I was feeling some vibration in my left wrist. What was that? It was nice vibration while my mind was clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*DISCLAIMER: It isn't that such phenomenons don't occur during Buddhist meditation, but typically such bodily phenomenons are not emphasized in most Buddhist traditions, and thus Buddhists lack the vocabulary. Tibetan Tantra practice is an exception, but that's because it derives a lot of its vocabulary and practices from tantric yoga. The subtle body is viewed in Buddhism as [personified impermanence.](http://newbuddhist.com/discussion/comment/243812/#Comment_243812)*

From your description it appears to be a spontaneous [Mula Bhandha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mula_Bandha). Like sneezing or coughing, spontaneous yogic postures are natural bodily occurrences, and are nothing to be wary of. They are triggered by conditions. For example, we sneeze in response to being in a room full of dust, similarly, when there are certain subtle energy manifestations in the body that are in need of correction, the body makes use of such locks or yoga mudras.

[image: Bandhas]
**Image source:** http://sequencewiz.org/2014/09/10/mula-bandha/

Without knowing more details about the quality and nature of vibration you felt, it would be hard to say for sure, but it sounds like [Piti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C4%ABti) / [Sukha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sukha). The clear mind you mention is likely the mind born of seclusion.

You can read more about Jhana factors by searching the web, but here's a [helpful summary](http://the-wanderling.com/jhana_factors.html). Also see a [similar question on this site](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/5996/kundalini-experiences-during-meditation?s=1%7C1.4567).

I'd recommend gaining reasonable perfection in either Hatha Yoga meditation, or in Buddhist meditation. Unless you have strong reasons for doing so, dabbling with both at the same time can be unproductive.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Should we also close the question as being off-topic i.e. unrelated to Buddhism?

Comment: I'm not sure, since this is partly about piti / sukha. In any case, I've experienced such bhandhas during vipassana and struggled to find Buddhist texts that explain them.

Comment: FWIW, Buddhism lacking a vocabulary for this sort of thing has not stopped us from discussing it in the past. For example, there's 1 question and 9 answers that mention "kundalini" on this site - https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/search?q=kundalini

Comment: @Buddho, sorry, but does "Has anyone experienced contraction of the PC muscle during (samatha) meditation" mean spontaneous? Cuz for me it was like urge and i just satisfied it.

Comment: Yes, but it was an urge that was pleasurable to give in, so I'd classify it as spontaneous - usually that's how Bandhas and asanas manifest - whereas mudras are more spontaneous like sneezes. It's another thing that there's only a miniscule difference since these bandha urges occur during stages of meditation when normal urges like sneezes are controllable.

Comment: I mean it was spontaneous urge, but not spontaneous contraction (like in question). So I experienced not contraction itself but urge and then contracted muscle. In other part I agree.

Comment: @ar7max I've edited the question to make it clearer in Buddhist terms, please roll back or modify if I've misrepresented what you intended to ask. Thanks.

Comment: @Buddho, thank you, question is clear and correct enough for me.

Comment: @ChrisW, I vote it is definitely related to Buddhism. Probably most long-time practitioners of meditation have experienced things like this.

Comment: @Adamokkha how about short-time? It was third time for me